# Properly accessing a segue's destination view controller to assign protocol delegates

Tags: ios, delegates, controller, protocols, segue

I'm encountering some problems in integrating segue and protocols while implementing a selection list.

In my selection list .h I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SelectionListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)rowChosen:(NSInteger)row;
@end

@interface SelectColor : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
-(IBAction)saveSelectedColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SelectionListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In my selection list .m I have:

```
@implementation SelectColori
@synthesize delegate;

//this method is called from a button on ui
-(IBAction)saveSelectedColore
{
    [self.delegate rowChosen:[lastIndexPath row]];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I would like to access to this selection list view by performing a segue from another table view:

```
@implementation TableList
...
- (void)selectNewColor
{
    SelectColor *selectController = [[SelectColor alloc] init];
    selectController.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectController animated:YES];

    //execute segue programmatically
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SelectColorSegue" sender: self];
}

- (void)rowChosen:(NSInteger)row
{
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Title" message:@"Error Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
```

If I navigate to the selection list using:

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectController animated:YES];

the alert is displayed. If I instead use:

> [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SelectColorSegue" sender: self];

no alert is displayed, because, I think, I don't pass to the destination selection list the selectController. Any ideas to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using Segue to pass data to the destinationViewController you need to use the method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SelectColorSegue"]) {
        SelectColor *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

from the Apple Docs

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can
>   override it and use it to pass any relevant data to the view
>   controller that is about to be displayed. The segue object contains
>   pointers to both view controllers among other information.