# push view controller with arguments using ios5 and storyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit, xcode-storyboard

I am developing an iPad application using sdk 5 and storyboard from an already working iPhone app (developed with separete xibs). I understand how storyboard works but I would like to push a view controller with arguments. Button calls logIn2 action like:

```
   - (IBAction)logIn2: (NSString *)strUser: (NSString *)strPass
{
    userViewController *UserViewController = [[userViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"userViewController" bundle:nil stringOne:strUser stringTwo:strPass];
    //UserViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [[self navController] pushViewController:UserViewController animated:YES];
}
```

this was working properly but with sdk 5 returns an error at first line. How to push view with arguments? Thank you.

Comment: error: receiver type 'userViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:stringOne:stringTwo:' [4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you want to convert your app to use Storyboard and Segues then you would make a Segue to push UserViewController. Put some properties in UserViewController to store the arguments. Then override prepareForSegue and set the properties in it. See this answer for more details:

[Properly accessing a segue's destination view controller to assign protocol delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533730/segue-delegate-and-protocol/8534630#8534630)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty obvious from the error message that there isn't a method declare initWithNibName:bundle:stringOne:stringTwo:' on your UserViewController. How is your UserViewController looks like?

Comment: - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil stringOne:(NSString *)aStringOne stringTwo:(NSString *)aStringTwo
{

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the custom initializer in your .h file? Otherwise only the standard initWithNibName initializer will be found as selector and not your designated one - hence the error message.

Comment: Declaring it in the header isn't enough; one must also implement it in the .m.